# Select first and last row value from 7 selected rows PHP/SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select the 1st and last row(row 7) from 7 rows pulled from MySQL table.
Looking at nesting a query is really confusing me to be honest.
Using >

```
select location, value1, reading_time from sensordata
where id in 
(
    SELECT min(id)
    FROM sensordata
    WHERE id >= 0
    and date(`reading_time`) >= '2013-04-01'
    group by date(`reading_time`)
) 
ORDER BY `sensordata`.`reading_time` DESC 
LIMIT 7
```

This is working fine to pull the 7 days data I need(i want to use it to pull the last 7 days whenever the code is run) and displays the info I need to work with.
But, I then want to subtract the last(most recent) entry from the earlier entry(row 7) to show usage over the last 7 days.
This value, from column 'value1', is the only info I need and would like to display this, either by assigning a string to it or some other means.

When running the query i get this response in phpmyadmin(sorry its in text)>

location
..value1
...reading_time

```
Kero Tank 802.46 2021-07-02 00:28:17   <<<<<<<< A
Kero Tank 802.46 2021-07-01 00:28:17
Kero Tank 802.46 2021-06-30 00:28:17
Kero Tank 811.48 2021-06-29 00:28:18
Kero Tank 811.48 2021-06-28 00:28:17
Kero Tank 811.48 2021-06-27 00:27:51
Kero Tank 811.48 2021-06-26 00:27:47   <<<<<<<< B
```

I want the result of B-A for value1

using PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Help us help you, please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and your desired results

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: please share some example.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking window functions:

```
select distinct id, value1_last - value1_first
from (select sd.*,
             first_value(value1) over (partition by id order by reading_time) as value1_first,
             first_value(value1) over (partition by id order by reading_time desc) as value1_last
      from sensor_data sd
      where sd.id <> 0 and
            sd.reading_time >= '2013-04-01'
     ) sd;
```

Note:  The subquery is not strictly necessary.  I wrote it that way because I suspect there might be other columns that you want as well, so you really want aggregation rather than `select distinct`.

Comment: i have no removed the 2 middle lines, as i dont think they are needed, if i take out WHERE id <= 0
    and date(`reading_time`) >= '2013-04-01' then it still works fine, I tried what you suggested but it comes up with an error regarding first_value line 3. i dont need any other data really apart from the result of B minus A, it was only so i could see the correct data was being collected by the query.